# JavaScript onKeyUp closures with timeout

Tags: javascript, timeout, closures

Im trying to assign an onKeyUp event to all inputs within a form, using closures. the array `fields` contains all the names of the fields that require the event assigned to them. The array `ajaxFields` contains the names of the fields (from the array `fields`) that requires ajax validation.

```
function createEvents(fields,ajaxFields) {
    for(var x=0;x<fields.length;x++) {

        $('input[name='+fields[x]+']').keyup(function(field) { 
        //assign an onKeyUp event
            return function() {
                //some code using variable 'field' and array 'ajaxFields'
        }(fields[x]));
    }
}
```

I would like the onKeyUp function to be executed a second after the user has finished typing in that field, insted of every time the key is up (onKeyUp). this would save up a lot of processing space, not to mention the ajax calls. So far im using this:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout('validate()' ,1000);
```

You might have noticed that the function `validate()` doesn't exist, and thats because I dont know how to wrap the closures inside a named function, and im not even sure if I should...

So how do I do that?

**EDIT**: here is a current [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z43Bq/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and *should*) pass functions to `setTimeout` instead of strings.

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    // your code here
}, 1000);
```

So, in your `keyup`, try something like this:

```
$('input[name='+fields[x]+']').keyup(function(field) { 
//assign an onKeyUp event
    return function() {
        var that = this,
            $this = $(this);
        clearTimeout($this.data('timeout'));
        $this.data('timeout', setTimeout(function(){
            //some code using variable 'field' and array 'ajaxFields'
            // "this" will not be your element in here, make sure to use "that" (or "$this")
        }, 1000));
    };
}(fields[x]));
```

I save the timeout in `$this.data`, so that each element can have its own timeout, instead of using a global variable.

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z43Bq/3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you show how to combine this with closures?

Comment: Im not sure why, but it's not working. And I think you're missing a closing `}` right?

Comment: @webdeskil: Yes, I was missing a `}`.

Comment: It still doesnt work, I've added a jsfiddle to the original post, maybe this would help.

Comment: Looks like I just missed a `)`.  Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Z43Bq/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11243/discussion-between-webdeskil-and-rocket)

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code should look like:

```
var timer;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var fields = $('.field');
    var ajaxFields = $('.ajax-field');

    createEvents(fields, ajaxFields);
});

function createEvents(fields,ajaxFields) {
    // Use jQuery's "foreach" method
    $(fields).each(function(inx, field) {
        // Bind the listener here
        $(field).keyup(function(ev) {
            // Clear timeout if necessary
            if (timer != null) clearTimeout(timer);

            // Set the timeout
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                // Your code should here

                console.log('Fields: ', fields, '\nAjax Fields: ', ajaxFields, '\nTHE field: ', field);
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
}
```

Also checkout the fiddle for the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/BLyhE/

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working, check out my fiddle in the original post