# AngularJS unique slug validator directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, firebase

So currently, I am exploring the world of AngularJS and have encountered a problem.

I am building a very primitive blog application supported by Firebase, and I want to use Angular validation to check whether a slug is already in use. However, something is going wrong here. This is the directive that I wrote to check whether a slug is already in use (**without Firebase**):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lk6fY/1/

As you can see, this works like a charm. Now, I can insert the Firebase call here, instead of the primitive check, but this forms two problems:

1. On every keyup, a request would be send to Firebase. If this is an application for one user, this would not really be a problem, but imagine 5000 people at the same time trying to post a blog entry (which of course wouldn't happen, but I want to learn the right approach).
2. Nevertheless, I did try it, and it didn't really work as expected. I think it has to do with the response time to the Firebase servers, because:

`foo-bar` would be valid, until the user pressed the submit button, whereas `foo-ba` would be invalid, but after pressing the submit button the user could simply continue.

So therefore my question: how can this be solved in an efficient an appropriate manner? 
Ideally, I would like the directive to connect to Firebase after either the title or slug fields are not anymore in focus. How would this be possible?

Comment: I'm trying to learn Angular, too, so this I may be way off base here.  Why not do local validation during entry (i.e. at every keystroke), but do server side validation only after the user hits the `submit` button?  That way, the server gets to validate only once and all of the intermediate validation occurs at the client.

Comment: Maybe using $timeout ? This is an anwser coming from another question : http://jsfiddle.net/Z43Bq/3/ and the question is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588994/javascript-onkeyup-closures-with-timeout?rq=1

Comment: @andand: yeah, that is an option which I thought about too, but I posted it here anyway because there might be a better option of which I am unaware of. Bonatoc: that could maybe work too, I might try that later.

Comment: ngBlur and ngChange events should be helpful here? You can decide at what point you push the data back to Firebase, so these would be great events to monitor

Comment: @andad: in the end, I chose to go for a server site validation. That is: the user presses submit, after which a request is sent to the server to check whether that slug exists. Problem is now: the template resolves before Firebase's callback. I think this is fixable by using UI-Router's resolve function, but I have the feeling that it is becoming way too cumbersome then... Any thoughts? Or do I need to make a fiddle to show it?